# Javascript function return output as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I'm new to Javascript and I'm currently trying to create a simple program consists of 2 functions which one is calculating total of student grades and the other is to calculate the the average of the grade. Here's the code

```js
var grades = [80, 87, 94, 82, 62, 98, 81, 81, 74, 91];

var sum = 0;

function accumulatedGrades(){
    for (index = 0; index<grades.length; index++){
        sum += grades[index];
    }
    
    return sum / grades.length;
}


function tests(){
    document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = document.write(sum/grades.length);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        
        <script src="js/example.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <h2 style="color: blueviolet">Grades</h2>
        
        <h3>This is all the grades: <br>80, 87, 94, 82, 62, 98, 81, 81, 74, and 91</h3>
        
        
        
        <h2 style="color: blueviolet">Average</h2>
        
        <h3 id='average'><script>tests()</script></h3>
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

I've tried to play around with the *function tests()* and used *document.write()* but I the output I've seen so far is undefined or no output is showing at all.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` for this at all

Comment: Does this means it should be something like this? `document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = (sum/grades.length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accumulatedGrades` function is never called so `sum` is 0.
`document.write` and `innerHTML` does not work as you have given. `document.write` writes on the document and `innerHTML` is the property of individual element.
`tests` function is not available in html file.
I have updated the code, fixed the `accumulatedGrades` function to calculate the sum correctly. Fixed the html and calling the `tests` function in js file itself.

```js
var grades = [80, 87, 94, 82, 62, 98, 81, 81, 74, 91];

var sum = 0;

function accumulatedGrades() {
  for (index = 0; index < grades.length; index++) {
sum += grades[index];
  }
  return sum;
}

function tests() {
  document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = (accumulatedGrades()) / grades.length;
}

tests()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        
        <script src="js/example.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h2 style="color: blueviolet">Grades</h2>
        <h3>This is all the grades: <br>80, 87, 94, 82, 62, 98, 81, 81, 74, and 91</h3>
        <h2 style="color: blueviolet">Average</h2>
        <h3 id='average'></h3>

    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. The solution works and helps me to understand this better!

Answer (score 0):

document.write() can delete content if it is called after the page loaded.

```
function averageGrades(){
    for (index = 0; index<grades.length; index++){
        sum += grades[index];
    }
    
    return sum / grades.length;
}

document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = averageGrades();
```

Check this code and let me know if it needs explanation.